# How to increment a variable and overwrite the old one?

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to Objective C, and I'm quite confused that the method:

```
-(void)increment 
{
  count = count+1;
}
```

doesn't increment the variable count on any method call, but just sets the variable on "1", no matter how often i call the method. This is different in Objective-C isnt it? In other languages it´s pretty basic.

Help would be great, thanks anyway guys.

Comment: Can you show us how you're using it? As written, the `increment` method is correct.

Comment: It does work the way you expect. If you called that method twice on the same object, its `count` variable would then be two higher. If you don't see it working that way, you're just doing something wrong and we'll need to see your code to tell you what.

Comment: As Chuck said, increment is correct. Post the rest of the code; the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

If that is not an instance variable, you need to statically initialize it. Try this:

```
-(void)increment {
    static int count = 0;
    count = count + 1; // Alternatively written as count++;
}
```

If you want it to be an instance variable, you need to declare it in your header file. In that case, do this instead:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject {
    int count;
}
```

Then your `increment` method should work properly.

Comment: thanks for the quick response! Hmm the count variable is actually declared in the header file, exactly as shown.